# How to Set Text of TinyMCE Editor to Center Align?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, function, tinymce

I'm trying to make it so a text editor that uses TinyMCE will have the text center-aligned by default. I've tried executing a command, and I've also tried linking to a custom CSS, but neither option worked. I'm not sure if my setup functions are written wrong, if my custom css isn't reaching to the right file location, or if the custom css isn't connecting to the right element.

Here is the TinyMCE init code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#writeTitle',
    width : "1000",
    height: '80',
    //skin: 'oxide-dark',
    //content_css: 'https://headcanon.ca/wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/70.css',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function (e) {
           editor.execCommand('JustifyCenter', false);
           editor.execCommand('FontSize', '32px', false);
        });
        editor.on('init keydown change', function (e) {
           document.getElementById('data').innerText = editor.getContent();
        });
    },
    
    //
});
</script>
```

And here is the CSS I've been trying:

```
.mce-content-body {
    background-color: #444445!important;
    color:#FFF!important;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting all the text in the editor to center align?  Are you just wanting the initial content to center align?  What happens when someone presses `Enter` to start a new block of text?

Comment: Yeah, I just want to make all the text center-aligned. In regards to when someone presses Enter, I was planning on trying to set it so it to a set length but right now I'm just focused on the text alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the CSS you want to use for this purpose you can use either the `content_css` or `content_style` configuration options in TinyMCE to pass the appropriate CSS to TinyMCE.

Here is an example:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/36haab

This uses the following CSS:

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    html {
        display: table;
        margin: auto;
    }

    body {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

I am not suggesting this is the only CSS that will do what you want but in my testing it does center all the text in the editor.

Comment: Yeah, this worked for me. Content_css was still being annoying even if this part worked, but it did for content_style which I didn't know about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put below styles to **list.css** file

```
.mce-content-body ol[align="center"],
.mce-content-body ol li[align="center"],
.mce-content-body ul[align="center"],
.mce-content-body ul li[align="center"] {
    text-align: center;
}
.mce-content-body ol[align="left"],
.mce-content-body ol li[align="left"],
.mce-content-body ul[align="left"],
.mce-content-body ul li[align="left"] {
    text-align: left;
}
.mce-content-body ol[align="right"],
.mce-content-body ol li[align="right"],
.mce-content-body ul[align="right"],
.mce-content-body ul li[align="right"] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

And then use it on `tinymce.init()` function

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#tinymce-textarea',
    content_css: ['<strong>list.css</strong>']
});
```